# does JPA use JavaBeans BeanInfo information?

Tags: jpa, javabeans

According to the JPA 2.1 spec:

> It is required that the entity class follow the method signature
>   conventions for JavaBeans read/write properties
>   (as defined by the JavaBeans Introspector class)
>   for persistent properties when property access is used.
>
> In this case, for every persistent property *property* of type *T*
>   of the entity, there is a getter method, *getProperty*,
>   and setter method *setProperty*.

Does this imply that the methods must *always* be named `getProperty`
and `setProperty`
(per the design pattern "convention" in §8.3.1 of JavaBeans spec 1.0.1,
"[i]f we don't find explicit BeanInfo on a class");
or could a `BeanInfo` class be provided to direct the JPA implementation
to a different method
(per the full description of the `Introspector` class in that spec)?

Although I'm also curious about how Hibernate or other JPA implementations
implement this,
I'm instead really asking what implementation the JPA spec requires.

Comment: I'm looking for supported facts, not opinions, of course, so I guess I'd really need to hear from someone on the JPA spec committee.

Answer (score 1):

The methods MUST be named as per the Java Beans contract ... getXXX (or isXXX), setXXX. There is no BeanInfo hook used by any JPA implementation I know of